# Cross domain AJAX request to Amazon S3

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cross-domain

Is there any way to enable an AJAX request sent from a server to Amazon S3?

I have a video player that loads subtitles using AJAX request and I would like to store the subtitles on Amazon S3, but obviously I've got an Cross-Origin error.

Answer (score 5):

Relatively new but I believe it should solve the problem: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html

Answer (score 1):

There's only a limited number of HTTP headers supported by S3 and Access-Control-Allow-* headers are not … So you have to wait till Amazon will implement this feature.

Source: [AWS Developer Forums: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34281&start=200&tstart=0)

Last official statement from an AWS team member (Jun 19, 2012):

> I just wanted to re-iterate that we are aware of the further requests
>   for this feature. And we are continuing to look into this feature and
>   we appreciate the continued feedback on this.
>
> We will provide further information as it becomes available.

Comment: hi, just want to ask if there's any update regarding to this? Did they alloew Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? thanks.